# How to ignore or delete packages that are kept back?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, sudo

I get this message in terminal when trying to upgrade:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
```

```
apt-cache policy linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
linux-generic:
  Installed: 5.4.0.67.70
  Candidate: 5.4.0.70.73
  Version table:
     5.4.0.70.73 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.4.0.67.70 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.4.0.26.32 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
linux-headers-generic:
  Installed: 5.4.0.67.70
  Candidate: 5.4.0.70.73
  Version table:
     5.4.0.70.73 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.4.0.67.70 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.4.0.26.32 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-generic:
  Installed: 5.4.0.67.70
  Candidate: 5.4.0.70.73
  Version table:
     5.4.0.70.73 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.4.0.67.70 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.4.0.26.32 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

```
grep -r "^deb\ " /etc/apt/ --include=*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxlite.list:deb http://repo.linuxliteos.com/linuxlite/ emerald main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```

Is there a command to ignore or delete these 3? I don't want to keep seeing the message that they are being kept back. Thanks.

Comment: Removing these essential packages is a bad idea. Please add output of `apt-cache policy linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic` and `grep -r "^deb\ " /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` to the question.

Comment: Try `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-headers-5.4.0-70 linux-headers-5.4.0-70-generic linux-image-5.4.0-70-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-70-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-70-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
3 to upgrade, 5 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade. full-upgrade works!

Comment: Whats with the linuxlite repo?  Are you running Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm running linux lite OS because my laptop is slow and old, it's based on Ubuntu 20.04.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

In most circumstances where the system is working properly, this will install 'kept-back' packages.

These packages usually involve a change of the package *name* (which a normal `upgrade` cannot handle).

For example, migrating from package `linux-image-extra-4.8.0-34-generic` to `linux-image-extra-4.8.0-37-generic` involves a change of package name.